# Using GroupBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a database table that contains entries for every SMS customers have sent. It looks something like this:

```
CustomerId  SentBy  SentTo SentDate
```

I want to create a report that lists the total amount of sent SMS messages per customer, using LINQ (preferably fluent syntax)

```
var smses = smsTable.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId);
```

I'm not quite sure how to loop through the result, though. I want the following output:

```
CustomerId  SmsCount
----------------------
1234        1756
100         333
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx), the GroupBy returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,
>   TElement>>`and each IGrouping object contains a
>   collection of objects of type TElement and a key.

Which means you can get the value of grouped item will be equal to the `Key` and each Key will associated with a collection. In your case you have to get the Key as well as the Count of items in each Group. for that the following code can be used.

```
var smses = smsTable.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
                    .Select(y => new 
                                 { 
                                    CustomerId = y.Key,
                                    smsCount = y.Count()
                                 });
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
var smses = smsTable.GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId).Select(group =>
                         new
                         {
                             CustomerId = group.Key,
                             SmsCount = group.Count()
                         });
```

Hope it helps!